# Power BI DAX - Calculate a delay with filter and avoid circular dependency

Tags: powerbi, dax, delay, circular-dependency

I'm using Power BI (DAX) and I have a problem problem that I couldn't solve.

You can find below an exemple of my problem.

An ID is a workflow. I need to find the delay each time I have a status between the line of the status and the oldest line without a status, considering that the delay start again to the next line

| ID | Time | Status | Result I want |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 01/07/2020 04:07:00 |  |  |
| ABC | 03/07/2020 04:14:00 |  |  |
| ABC | 06/07/2020 06:27:00 | Done | 4,0917 |
| XYZ | 11/06/2020 04:03:00 |  |  |
| XYZ | 12/06/2020 04:02:00 | To check | 0,9993 |
| XYZ | 15/06/2020 04:02:00 |  |  |
| XYZ | 16/06/2020 04:04:00 | Transfered | 1,0014 |
| XYZ | 17/06/2020 04:14:00 |  |  |
| XYZ | 21/06/2020 04:34:00 |  |  |
| XYZ | 30/06/2020 04:14:00 | Done | 13,0000 |
| MON | 07/09/2020 09:49:00 | Cancelled | 0,0000 |

What I did was created an another column Filter 1 and Filter 2 to create an index like below

| ID | Time | Status | Filter1 | Filter2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 01/07/2020 04:07:00 |  | 0 | 1 |
| ABC | 03/07/2020 04:14:00 |  | 0 | 1 |
| ABC | 06/07/2020 06:27:00 | Done | 1 | 1 |
| XYZ | 11/06/2020 04:03:00 |  | 0 | 3 |
| XYZ | 12/06/2020 04:02:00 | To check | 1 | 3 |
| XYZ | 15/06/2020 04:02:00 |  | 0 | 2 |
| XYZ | 16/06/2020 04:04:00 | Transfered | 1 | 2 |
| XYZ | 17/06/2020 04:14:00 |  | 0 | 1 |
| XYZ | 21/06/2020 04:34:00 |  | 0 | 1 |
| XYZ | 30/06/2020 04:14:00 | Done | 1 | 1 |
| MON | 07/09/2020 09:49:00 | Cancelled | 1 | 1 |

The formula for filter1 is :`IF('test communauté'[Filter0]="YES",IF('test communauté'[Status]=BLANK(),0,1),0)`

For Filter 2 is :

```
VAR currentid = 'test communauté'[ID]
VAR maxtime = VALUE(CALCULATE(MAX('test communauté'[Time]),'test communauté'[ID]=currentid))
VAR test = SUMX( 
                FILTER ( 'test communauté',              
                        'test communauté'[Time] >= maxtime
                        &&  'test communauté'[ID] = currentid
                        &&  'test communauté'[Filter0] = "YES" 
                         ),
                'test communauté'[Filter1])
return test
```

And when I try to use this column filter2 to create a formula for my delay, I have a circular dependency. I don't know how to avoid this error. Keep in mind that I need the delay in column in the end and not as a measure because I will need it to calculate other KPI.

Thank you for your help,

Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REMOVEFILTERS in maxtime to remove the dependency of Filter2 from Filter1

```
Filter 2 =
VAR currentid = 'test communauté'[ID]
VAR maxtime =
    VALUE (
        CALCULATE (
            MAX ( 'test communauté'[Time] ),
            'test communauté'[ID] = currentid,
            REMOVEFILTERS ( 'test communauté'[Filter1] )
        )
    )
VAR test =
    SUMX (
        FILTER (
            'test communauté',
            'test communauté'[Time] >= maxtime
                && 'test communauté'[ID] = currentid
                && 'test communauté'[Filter0] = "YES"
        ),
        'test communauté'[Filter1]
    )
RETURN
    test
```

Also read these posts:

1. [A circular dependency in Power Bi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66929072/a-circular-dependency-in-power-bi/67031704#67031704)
2. [Circular Dependency between Calculated Columns in a Fact Table](https://www.antmanbi.com/post/circular-dependency-between-calculated-columns-in-a-fact-table)